# VPN on a Cocoa app

Tags: macos, cocoa, connection, vpn

I'm developing an app for a customer. He has a company and he wants the app to connect to the other Macs via VPN. Does anyone know a good tutorial/guide for that?

Comment: You accepted a job without knowing the fundamentals of what you had to do? Geez. I'm going about my consulting the wrong way...

Comment: I didn't accept anything yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apps don't VPN; the operating system does. Then your app just happily notices it's able to see a server it wouldn't otherwise have been able to had the connection not been present.

Comment: Thanks!I noticed that a few time ago. I'm not a network specialist :/